# How to convert milliseconds to the date ( day of the month )?

Tags: javascript, date, time, epoch

I need to get the date ( day of the month ) from UNIX epoch time .
I can get the date from this:

```
new Date ().getDate()
```

But I need to get from `Date.now()`, `Date.now().getDate()` gives me an error..

How to get that date ( day of the month ) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass number of miliseconds to `Date` constructor like:

```js
let now = Date.now();
let date = new Date(now).getDate();
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this data from DB, should the milliseconds be saved as number or string? Cause I am still getting errors

Comment: @itneg did you try the number ?

Comment: i figured it out.  Cause there are two formats of number in mongodb, int32 and int64, also Epoch timestamp and  timestamp in milliseconds which has 3 zeros more.. Thanks for the help

Comment: unix epoch time is in seconds, not milliseconds